# How to skip iframe video to the next

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, youtube, dart

```
 <iframe width="500" height="500" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/OWsyrnOBsJs"></iframe>

 <button>Skip Video</button>
```

I have set up iframe to embed the youtube video. When the video is over it gives me new recommended videos I can click and play. I was wondering how can I set up my button(skip video) to skip the video and auto play the next recommend video or perhaps the next video in the playlist?

Maybe HTML5 won't be enough so I might have to use JavaScript or Dart. What is the easiest way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I advise you to use the YouTube JavaScript Player API.
There are many helpful methods to play the next video etc. It is very nice documentated.

[Documentation Youtube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference?hl=en)

Comment: It doesn't seem to have skip to recommend video